# SQL Query from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I currently have two tables that look something like this:

**Table 1**

```
Id | AddressNumber | AddressStreet | AddressZip
------------------------------------------------
1   | 50           | Fake          | 60101
2   | 300          | Fake          | 60101
3   | 50           | Fake2         | 60101
4   | 50           | Fake          | 60103
```

**Table 2**

```
AddressLowRange | AddressHighRange | AddressStreet | AddressZip
---------------------------------------------------------------
50             | 200              | Fake          | 60101
20             | 50               | Other Fake    | 70102
```

I need to find a list of Ids from table 1 where the address is not in Table 2.
So for the sample data above i'd get back ids 2, 3 & 4.

Comment: Looks like none of the rows are in range, so they should all be returned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table1.AddressNumber BETWEEN Table2.AddressLowRange AND Table2.AddressHighRange
        AND Table1.AddressStreet = Table2.AddressStreet
        AND Table1.AddressZip = Table2.AddressZip
    )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

does the address is not in Table 2 means addressStreet

if so:

```
select id from table1 where addressStreet not in (select distinct addressstreet from table2)
```

and

```
select * from table1 where addressStreet not in (select distinct addressstreet from table2)
```

for all fields

Comment: It means the entire address. Street, Number, & Zip

Answer (score 1):

```
select id from "Table 1"
where AddressStreet not in (select distinct AddressStreet from "Table 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to consider the number range, unlike most of the other answers.  Something like this should work:

```
select Id
  from Table1
 where Id not in (select T1.Id
                    from Table1 T1
                    join Table2 T2 on (T1.AddressNumber between T2.AddressLowRange and T2.AddressHighRange)
                                   and T1.AddressStreet = T2.AddressStreet
                                   and T1.AddressZip = T2.AddressZip)
```

or slightly simplified...

```
select T1.Id
  from #table1 T1
  left join #table2 T2 on (T1.AddressNumber between T2.AddressLowRange and T2.AddressHighRange)
                      and T1.AddressStreet = T2.AddressStreet
                      and T1.AddressZip = T2.AddressZip
 where T2.AddressLowRange is null
```